# Remove special character ? from url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect this url:

http://www.domena.pl/?tekst,123.html

to this

http://www.domena.pl/tekst,123.html

I just want to remove ? after first /, so I would like to redirect every url domena/?...... to domena/......

I was using this htaccess and it works for domena/testtekst,123, but I don't know how I should change it to work with special character ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domena.pl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test(.*)$
RewriteRule ^test(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domena.pl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^?(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and this doesn't work too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domena.pl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^\?(.*)$ http://www.domena.pl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```